# after I installed anaconda no new pip installed modules can be imported

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I recently installed `anaconda` and now I can't find the new modules anymore after I've installed them in this new `anaconda python` environment.

this is the location of the `python interpreter` for my `anaconda` environment I get when I type 'which `python`': `/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`

this is my `$PATH:`
`/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/user/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/user/.pyenv/shims:/Users/user/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/go/src/github.com:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:` No such file or directory

can anyone please tell me why `anaconda` can't find the modules I `pip install` in the `anaconda` environment when it has configured its own path? referring to these: `/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/condabin` in `$PATH` that came automatically with the installation.

my bash profile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/SirFalk/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/SirFalk/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/SirFalk/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/SirFalk/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: did you uninstall the standard python? do you have pip installed in multiple places? what does which pip say

Comment: Are you sure you're in the environment you installed the packages in? Packages installed in a conda virtual environment should only be accessible within the environment you installed them

Comment: Please share the contents of the environment.

Comment: some more info: im on a mac, mac:~ user$ pip3 install pygame
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.6), mac:~ user$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3, mac:~ user$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3.

python works perfectly fine in pycharm its just sublime text i cant import pygame

Comment: mac:~ user$ python3 -VV
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Comment: mac:~ user$ pip3 --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
mac:~ user$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with sublime text not knowing what python environment you want. Also, none of the environments you listed were anaconda environments. What does this have to do with anaconda?

Answer (score -1):

Anaconda relies heavily on virtual environments, which in turn have their own set of installed python packages. This is a good thing. It lets you switch between different versions of Python, as well as use different versions of packages for different projects, without any headaches caused by package dependency conflicts.

You need to reinstall packages for each virtual environment you create on anaconda, (but note that anaconda environments will inherit packages from the base anaconda environment). I recommend you don't install any extra packages in the base environment, though, to avoid dependency conflicts. I also highly recommend using the command line interface for Anaconda, as it is much faster than their GUI app.

In the terminal, cd to the directory containing your anaconda folder; (I recommend having the anaconda folder in your home directory for convenience).

Then activate conda (this enters the conda base environment):

```
source anaconda3/bin/activate
```

Create and enter a conda virtual environment

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
conda activate myenv
```

Note that you may have to type `. anaconda3/bin/activate` instead of using `source`, depending on your type of shell.

Now that you're in your virtual environment, you can install packages like so:

```
conda install jupyter
conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai pytorch torchvision cuda92
```

To leave your virtual environment:

```
conda deactivate
```

This returns to the base anaconda environment. To leave the base environment, type `conda deactivate` a second time.

Other useful stuff:

To enter an already created environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

To remove an environment package:

```
conda remove -n myenv package_name
```